# Adventure Works 2019: Adding New Person to Person.Person Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Right now I am using 3 stored procedures to Add a person to the person.person table.  I would like to cut this down to a single stored procedure to resolve this issue.

1. INSERT new GUID and DateModified to table Person.BusinessEntity
2. SELECT the auto generate BusinessEntityID form table Person.BusinessEntity
3. INSERT new Person to Person.Person Table

The Stored Procedures all use parameters which I pass via a C# application and I have confirmed that the a user is in fact added to the AdventureWorks2019 Db.

1. **Procedure:  Person.CreateNewBusinessEntity**

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO [Person].[BusinessEntity]
   (
       [BusinessEntity].rowguid
       , [BusinessEntity].ModifiedDate
   )
   VALUES
   (
       @RowGUID
       , GetDate()
   )
   ```
2. **Procedure:  Person.GetBusinessEntityID**

   ```sql
   SELECT 
       [BusinessEntityID]

   FROM 
       [AdventureWorks2019].[Person].[BusinessEntity]

   WHERE  [rowguid] = @RowGuid
   ```
3. **Procedure:  Person.CreateNewPerson**

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO [Person].[Person]
   (
       [BusinessEntityID]
       ,[PersonType]
       ,[NameStyle]
       ,[Title]
       ,[FirstName]
       ,[MiddleName]
       ,[LastName]
       ,[Suffix]
       ,[EmailPromotion]
       ,[AdditionalContactInfo]
       ,[Demographics]
       ,[rowguid]
       ,[ModifiedDate]
   )
   VALUES
   (
       @BusinessEntityID
       , @PersonType
       , @NameStyle
       , @Title
       , @FirstName
       , @MiddleName
       , @LastName
       , @Suffix
       , @EmailPromotion
       , @AdditionalContactInfo
       , @Demographics
       , @RowGUID
       , GetDate()
   )
   ```

Any help here is appreciated. Thanks!

Thanks to HABO, I am now using this solution.  Now I only need two procedures.

```
DECLARE @Inserted table ( [BusinessEntityID] int );


INSERT INTO [Person].[BusinessEntity]
(
    [BusinessEntity].rowguid
    , [BusinessEntity].ModifiedDate
)

OUTPUT inserted.[BusinessEntityID] INTO @Inserted([BusinessEntityID])

VALUES
(
    @RowGUID
    , GetDate()
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your question?

Comment: So what's stopping you putting them in one procedure?

Comment: I am not sure if I can do this via a Join or be able to select the BusienssEntityID and store as a variable in a stored procedure.

Comment: I guess I am looking also for additional options here that may work too?

Comment: Hint: Look at the [`OUTPUT` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for a way to capture the new `BusinessEntityId` during the `insert`.

Comment: Thanks HABO that solution worked I posted my changes to the bottom of my original question since I could not get the code formatting to work in this text box area.

Comment: You expect to get this done in a single Stored proc?  and you need to use the latest [BusinessEntityID] to insert the person to the person table. Am I getting the question correctly   ?

Answer (score 0):

The  below answer shows you how to get the inserted id and add it to the next insert in side the Same SP.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO
CREATE PROC  CreateNewPerson 
AS 
BEGIN


 DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE ([BusinessEntityID] INT, ModifiedDate DATETIME)
 DECLARE @BusinessEntityID AS INT  
 INSERT INTO [Person].[BusinessEntity]
  (
     [BusinessEntity].rowguid 
   , [BusinessEntity].ModifiedDate
  )
 --Get the output value inserted to a table. 
 OUTPUT inserted.[BusinessEntityID], inserted.ModifiedDate  INTO 
 @OutputTbl([BusinessEntityID],[ModifiedDate])
 VALUES
 (
     NEWID()
   , GetDate()
 )


 --Assigned to a variable. You can get this using subquery as well inside the insert statment. 
 SELECT @BusinessEntityID =  [BusinessEntityID] FROM  @OutputTbl

 INSERT INTO [Person].[Person]
 (
     [BusinessEntityID]
    ,[PersonType]
    ,[NameStyle]
    ,[Title]
    ,[FirstName]
    ,[MiddleName]
    ,[LastName]
    ,[Suffix]
    ,[EmailPromotion]
    ,[AdditionalContactInfo]
    ,[Demographics]
    ,[rowguid]
    ,[ModifiedDate]
   )
  VALUES

   (
    @BusinessEntityID
   , @PersonType --These columns with @ sign needed to be declared or supply values 
   , @NameStyle
   , @Title
   , @FirstName
   , @MiddleName
   , @LastName
   , @Suffix
   , @EmailPromotion
   , @AdditionalContactInfo
   , @Demographics
   , NEWID() --This will generate a new GUID for each row.
   , GetDate()
    )
  END
  GO
```

Second way is using  Scope_identity(). Replace the
"SELECT @BusinessEntityID =  [BusinessEntityID] FROM  @OutputTbl'
from below lines in the Sp will do the same thing for you.

```
  SELECT @BusinessEntityID =  SCOPE_IDENTITY() --[BusinessEntityID] FROM  @OutputTbl
  Select @BusinessEntityID
```

Comment: @Trypsin Get back to me if you have any questions . I am happy to help. Thanks